# Shortcode for External HTML

Tags: shortcode

I'm looking for a short-code that I can put in a page, that will open up a static external HTML file. The point is so I can update the file, and change the contents of the page with just uploading a new file to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Is a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flynsarmy-iframe-shortcode/) out of the question? Seems like that would be the exact solution to your problem.